# skipping controller name from URL in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've an existing project in symfony 1.4

For static pages, we use a module Page which give following URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/page/aboutus
http://www.example.com/page/faq
http://www.example.com/ (page/index method, points to method page/home)
```

For new requirements, we need URL in format:

```
http://www.example.com/aboutus
http://www.example.com/faq
http://www.example.com/  (index/home method of page module; working as page is default module)
```

There are 16 such static pages and all are listed under `page` module. As of now I'm planning to create 16 new modules with putting each static page in `index` method of new module but I guess its a bad solution and hope symfony is definitely not designed to be used in this way.

Is there any way to skip module name from URL, at least for default module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the route feature of symfony!

In `routing.yml`:

```
aboutus_page:
  url:   /aboutus
  param: { module: page, action: aboutus }

faq_page:
  url:   /faq
  params: { module: page, action: faq }

home_page:
  url:   /
  params: { module: page, action: index }

# your other routes
# ...
```

The `actions.class.php` of your `page` module will look like:

```
class pageActions extends sfActions
{
   public function executeAboutus (sfWebRequest $request)
   {
      // ...
   }

   public function executeFaq (sfWebRequest $request)
   {
      // ...
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a rewrite rule  as explained in
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: Thanks WFahl. URL Rewriting is definitely other solution and much better then creating 16 modules. I'll definitely prefer that over 16 modules. However I'm surprised if there is any buildin support in symfony for that? Codeigniter provide that support for skipping controller/module name from URL (not sure about other frameworks) and this is very common requirement that I hope symfony must also have some buildin support for that. +1 for suggesting mod-rewrite solution. I'll accept this answer if there is no build-in support in symfony 1.4 for skipping module name from URL.